# The FragmentManager must be attached to itshost to create a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using OkHttp library (version 4.9.0 but I doubt that is relevant).

Somewhere in my activity I need to check something remote and depending on the response update fragment.

Simplified, my code looks something like this:

```
val request = Request.Builder()
  .url(url)
  .post(requestData, "application/json")
  .build()

client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                // do something else, not relevant
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                try {
                  Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
                                supportFragmentManager.commit(true) {
                                    setReorderingAllowed(true)
                                    replace(R.id.container, MyFragment::class.java, argsBundle)
                                }
                  }
                } finally {
                    response.close()
                }
            }
        })
```

Now all this is fine and well, but we have come across a scenario where the user had the app opened, the request was made, but the user got an alert pop up from the OS (asking them to save password in their Gmail app).

Now this happened AFTER the request was made, so it promptly executed but when we got to `replace(R.id.container, MyFragment::class.java, argsBundle)` the app got the following exception

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The FragmentManager must be attached to itshost to create a Fragment

Stack trace:

```
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction.createFragment FragmentTransaction.java:200
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction.replace FragmentTransaction.java:374
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction.replace FragmentTransaction.java:341
```

(note that `itshost` smacked together comes from actual android support library code). I can't find anything in Google on the exception, but fundamentally I think the issue is with my architecture.

How can I check that activity is ready to operate on it's fragments when my async call is finished?